# Is there a benefit to charging a supercapacitor in parallel and then discharging in series?

Tags: supercapacitor

I'm interesting in building a hand crank charger for a 12V supercapacitor bank. I'll need multiple supercaps in series to hit 12V but to my novice understanding, it seems more efficient to charge in parallel and then switch to series for discharge. I get more capacitance and my resistance should be lower. Therefore reducing the crank torque of the hand crank. I'm looking for someone who knows way more than me to tell me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details about your system. What are the specs on the hand crank charger? What is the voltage rating of the capacitors? How are you switching between parallel and series?

Comment: Hi Dan, 2.85V, 3400F Maxwell Supercap. Project is to build the charger and the switch. Crank will be similar to the k-tor power box 120V 20W output and I thinking some kind of relay circuit for the switch.

Comment: ALWAYS in parallel, only.

Answer (score 1):

With a given hand-crank X and super capacitor Y, if you stack up several Y's to charge with X, this will be lighter work, but will take longer.
That last part is of course simply conservation of energy.

If crank X cannot supply the stacked voltage, you will not get them full and parallel would be an option.

Your initial conclusion is correct, you get a higher visible capacitance and lower resistance, but to a generator/crank this is actually "more work".
Think of a low resistance as a short circuit and a high resistance as unconnected wires. Try to turn the crank with nothing connected, then short the crank and try to turn it again.

You will soon find the short circuit is a lot more work.

Edit, due to your comment above:

Be aware that the K-Tor, as advertised, supplies 120VDC. No 12V at all. You will need a switching power supply to be able to transfer the 120VDC somewhat efficiently to a 12V bank of power buffers such as the caps you want to use. In which case you are free to optimise for the capacitor bank you build. (13V5 for 5caps stacked, for example).

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure to read the reviews on the super caps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'standard' technique.  There is a device called a Marx generator that is used to generate very high voltages.  It consists of a series of capacitors connected in parallel with resistors and in series with spark gaps.  The capacitors charge in parallel through the resistors, then discharge in series through the spark gaps, multiplying the input voltage by the number of capacitors.  Sounds like you want to do the same thing, but at a much lower voltage.

The same amount of energy will be stored in the capacitors in either configuration, so it's mainly a question of whether or not the parallel configuration will be beter for charging or not.  Adding the required switches to select between series and parallel will certainly add quite a bit of complexity, but it's not clear if it is worth it or not.  The switches could also require quite a bit of power to actuate, depending on what sort of a device you use; this power will not be available for your load.

It might be a good idea to look in to the characteristics of your generator.  If you put the caps in parallel, the voltage will change more slowly with the input current.  This could be a good configuration if you have a low voltage generator that can supply a lot of current.  Otherwise, it might be a better idea to put them in series.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look up Marx generators. Glad to know I wasn't totally off base.

Answer (score 0):

When your capacitors are paralleled, for charging, the total capacitance will be the sum of all the capacitances, the value of the equivalent series resistance (ESR) will be the  values of the individual ESRs in parallel, and the cranking will be much more difficult than if they were in series.

In series, for discharge, the voltage across the string will be the sum of the individual capacitor voltages, the total capacitance of the string will be the capacitance of an individual capacitor divided by the number of capacitors in the string, and the ESR will be the sum of the individual ESRs of the capacitors in the string.

Answer (score -1):

Charging a supercapacitor directory from a hand crank device not a good idea. Hand cranks tell for produce up and down voltage due to the variance of the crank by the user. Too low a voltage and no charging gets down, too high and the capacitor will be damaged. Supercapacitors are very sensitive to over voltage.

There is however a reliable way to accomplish this. Connect the crank output to a high voltage capacitor which will be used as a temporary power store. It will even out the power so that it can be used to charge the supercapacitors.

A constant voltage regulator with an adjustable current limit can then be used to safely charge the supercapacitors. The current limit should be adjusted to a point where it does not make it to difficult to power the hand crank.

If your hank crank puts out 120 VDC as mentioned by one of the other posters you will also need to find a way to reduce the voltage down to a reasonable level unless you can find a regulator than can handle the high voltage. You could try experimenting with small computer power supplies designed to operate at 120VAC. Some can operate off much lower voltages and could provide by the power storage tank and the voltage regulation in a pre-made device.

I would recommend putting the capacitors in series and using a chip designed for balancing the charge of the capacitors. This will make it easier to get an even charge across the capacitors.

When drawing power from supercapacitors you have to keep in mind that unlike a battery which will produce a fairly consistent output voltage the capacitors will drop off on a linear scale. Thus to get the most power out of the capacitors you need to start with a higher voltage than you need to power the load.

If you intend to power a 12V circuit the best way would be to stack the capacitors up to as much as 30 volts. Then use a buck-boost regulator to provide a 12V output. While the capacitors are at a higher voltage the regulator will operate in a buck mode reducing the voltage. When the capacitor voltage drops below 12V the regulator will boost the voltage up to 12V. This type of circuit will allow the capacitors to discharge down to around 4V depending on internal resistance of the capacitors, the load current, and the capabilities of the regulator.

Building a buck-boost regulator is not simple but by using existing design from a data sheet it is not beyond most builders with enough knowledge to build a linear regulator. You may also be able to find pre-made device available from surplus electronics sellers.